# Does Age of Empires 3 multiplayer still work?

Tags: age-of-empires-iii

I was wondering if the Multiplayer in Age of Empires 3 still exists.
I found nothing to this topic by research, so I assume that it still exists.
However, when I try to connect, **Connection to ESO lost** pops up.

Did I miss something or has the service been suspended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, it still exists. The servers are down right now, thats all.

Server status: http://www.agecommunity.com/_server_status_/